# How to get Python 3 to correctly handle unicode strings from MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, python-3.x, unicode, pymongo

I'm using Windows 7 64-bit, Python 3, MongoDB, and PyMongo. I know that in Python 3, all strings are unicode. I also know that MongoDB stores all strings as unicode. So I don't understand why, when I pull a document from my database where the value of a particular field is "C:\Some Folder\E=mc².xyz", Python treats that string as "C:\Some Folder\E=mcÂ².xyz". It doesn't just print that way; os.path.exists() returns False. Now, as if that wasn't confusing enough, if I save the string to a text file, and then open it with the encoding explicitly set to "utf-8", the string appears correctly, and os.path.exists() returns True. What's going wrong, and how do I fix it?

Edit:
Here's some code I just wrote to demonstrate my problem:

```
from pymongo import MongoClient

db = MongoClient().test_db
orig_doc = {'string': 'E=mc²'}
_id = db.test_col.insert(orig_doc)
new_doc = db.test_col.find_one(_id)
print(new_doc['string'])

>>> E=mc²
```

As you can see, it works exactly as it should! Thus I now realize that I must've messed up when I migrated from PostgreSQL. Now I just need to fix the strings. I know that it's possible, but there's got to be a better way than writing the strings to a text file and then reading them back. I *could* do that, just as I did in my previous testing, but it just doesn't seem like the right way.

Comment: Could you include some code? It seems you're missing a setting or call that specifies the encoding. Nothing really seems to be going wrong, you're only getting the data back in an incorrect encoding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't store Unicode.  It is a concept.  MongoDB has to be using an encoding of Unicode, and it looks like `UTF-8`.  Python 3 Unicode strings are stored internally as one of a number of encodings depending on the content of the string.  What you have is a string decoded to Unicode with the wrong encoding:

```
>>> s='"C:\Some Folder\E=mcÂ².xyz"'  # The invalid decoding.
>>> print(s)
"C:\Some Folder\E=mcÂ².xyz"
>>> print(s.encode('latin1').decode('utf8'))  # Undo the wrong decoding, and apply the right one.
"C:\Some Folder\E=mc².xyz"
```

There's not enough information to tell you how to read MondoDB correctly, but this should help you along.

Comment: Your reply came in just before I finished editing my post. I just tested your solution and it works! Thanks a bunch!